# ThreeJS - how to set current time in Animation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using skinning / skeletal animation in ThreeJS. I have an animation, and I want to be able to move backward and forward through it, and jump to different locations within it, rather than the usual looping behaviour.

The animation is created like this, as in the example:

```
var animation = new THREE.Animation( mesh, geometry.animation.name );
```

I have tried updating the animation with negative deltas, as well as setting animation.currentTime directly:

```
animation.currentTime = animationLocation;
```

These appear to work only if I move forward in time, but if I go backward the animation breaks and I get an error:

```
THREE.Animation.update: Warning! Scale out of bounds: ... on bone ...
```

One thing that does actually work without error is to call `stop()` and then `play()` with a new start time:

```
animation.stop();
animation.play( true, animationLocation );
```

...however when I look at what these functions are actually doing, they involve many many function calls, looping, resetting transforms etc. This seems like a horrible way to do it, even if it works as a hack.

It may be that this functionality does not exist yet, in which case I'll try to dig in and create a function that does a minimal amount of work, but I'm hoping there is another way that I haven't found.

Can anyone help with this?

[UPDATE]

As an update on my progress, I'll post the best solution I have at this time...

I pulled out the contents of the `stop()` and `play()` functions, and stripped out everything I could, making some assumptions about certain values having already been set by 'play()'.

This still seems like it is probably not the best way to do it, but it is doing a bit less work than by just calling `stop()` then `play()`.

This is what I was able to get it down to:

```
THREE.Animation.prototype.gotoTime = function( time ) {

    //clamp to duration of the animation:
    time = THREE.Math.clamp( time, 0, this.length );

    this.currentTime = time;

    // reset key cache
    var h, hl = this.hierarchy.length,
        object;

    for ( h = 0; h < hl; h ++ ) {

        object = this.hierarchy[ h ];

        var prevKey = object.animationCache.prevKey;
        var nextKey = object.animationCache.nextKey;

        prevKey.pos = this.data.hierarchy[ h ].keys[ 0 ];
        prevKey.rot = this.data.hierarchy[ h ].keys[ 0 ];
        prevKey.scl = this.data.hierarchy[ h ].keys[ 0 ];

        nextKey.pos = this.getNextKeyWith( "pos", h, 1 );
        nextKey.rot = this.getNextKeyWith( "rot", h, 1 );
        nextKey.scl = this.getNextKeyWith( "scl", h, 1 );

    }

    //isPlaying must be true for update to work due to "early out"
    //so remember the current play state:
    var wasPlaying = this.isPlaying;
    this.isPlaying = true; 

    //update with a delta time of zero:
    this.update( 0 );

    //reset the play state:
    this.isPlaying = wasPlaying;

}
```

The main limitation of the function in terms of usefulness is that you can't interpolate from one arbitrary time to another. You can basically just scrub around in the animation.

Comment: Very interesting question... I was working on an animation imported from collada, and wanted to reset the animation to frame 0 immediately after stopping it. I mistakenly tried to do so by using -> animation.update(0) -> animation.stop(), but after reading your question, tried animation.update(0) -> animation.play(false, 0) -> animation.stop()... And it's appears to work consistently. As for your problem (wanting to play animations in reverse), the first thought I had, was to just animate the reverse frames, and playback from the start of that...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My goal was not so much to play it forward and backward, but to be able to jump around from pose to pose, interpolating between them without having to go through the frames in between. I think you can do this with morph target animations already. I noticed the other day that the morph target animations now support playing in reverse as well. Skinning is a lot more involved I think, so I guess it will take longer to have the same features.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `THREE.Clock` and assign `startTime`, `oldTime`, `elapsedTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I didn't notice it until now. I will check this out tonight...

Comment: Hi again. From what I can tell, THREE.Clock is just used to get delta times for each frame. I should have mentioned in the original question that I did try updating the animation with negative deltas, but the effect was the same as setting currentTime ( ie the animation broke. ) Please let me know if I am not interpreting your answer correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just completely gave up on trying to set the animation time directly, and finally accepted that I'd have to use the hack I had thought of early in my google journey . I feel like this is fairly optimized, because it only takes a single function call which is intended to be called every frame anyways. I've had no issues with my method yet.

The core functionality of my method is to loop the animation, and abuse the `update()` function to set the animation position to where we want it, when needed, instead of updating it by delta time as intended. The example below also refrains from rendering or updating anything unless necessary.

The purpose of my code was to control the animation position directly with a slider

```
let time = 0;
let lastSliderPos = 0;
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let mixer = null;

mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(yourModelHereLikeGLTFForExample); 
//Call inside mesh file load callback


function render(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    
    let newframe = lastSliderPos != slider.value;
    
    if (newframe){
        if (mixer){
            mixer.update( anim.duration + (slider.value - lastSliderPos));
            lastSliderPos = slider.value;
        }

        // stop rendering every frame to save performance when not moving                
        if (camera){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically, this would accumulate floating point precision errors since it's relative to the previous frame's float and not absolute time.

A better generalized solution which should work with any position, and should stay precise:

```
// Call these four lines inside the model load callback
anim = gltf.animations[0];
anim.optimize();
animAction = mixer.clipAction(anim);
animAction.play();

function setAnimTime(t){
    if ( mixer ){
        mixer.update( anim.duration + (t - animAction.time));
    }
}
```

or if you want to control multiple animation clips (but less efficiently)

```
function setAnimTime(a, t){
    aAction = mixer.clipAction(a);
    if ( mixer ){
        mixer.update( a.duration + (t - aAction.time));
    }
}
```

It is important to make sure the animation is playing before calling `setAnimTime()`. Play/Stop can be integrated into the function, but that would make it no better than OP's second solution.

Hope this helps, any improvements/suggestions are welcome :)

Edit: Theoretically, you should be able to call the update based on delta time as normal as well, so you can have the animation playing and still scrub to a new position without having to do anything different. Doesn't add anything, just an observation I figured may be useful...